# Scala pattern matching variable binding

Tags: scala, extractor

Why can't I bind the variable in @-style when the extractor return `Option[<Type>]`? I.e. this one does not work:

```
object IsUpperCase {
  def unapply(s: String): Option[String] = {
    if (s.toUpperCase() == s) {
      Some(s)
    } else {
      None
    }
  }
}

val s = "DuDu@qwadasd.ru"
s match {
  case u @ IsUpperCase() => println("gotcha!") // what? "wrong number of arguments for object IsUpperCase"?
  case _ => 
}
```

But this one works!

```
val s = "DuDu@qwadasd.ru"
s match {
  case IsUpperCase(u) => println("gotcha!")
  case _ => 
}
```

From the other hand, if `IsUpperCase` looks like this:

```
object IsUpperCase {
  def unapply(s: String): Boolean = {
    return s.toUpperCase() == s
  }
}
```

Then the first example works, and the second does not! Why is it this way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> what? "wrong number of arguments for object IsUpperCase"?

```
case u @ IsUpperCase() => println("gotcha!")
```

Well, yes. The return type of `unapply` is `Option[String]`, which means the pattern match of `IsUpperCase` *must* accept a parameter, like this:

```
case u @ IsUpperCase(_) => println("gotcha!") // I don't care about the parameter
```

The `unapply` definition that fits the first pattern is this:

```
object IsUpperCase {
  def unapply(s: String): Boolean = s.toUpperCase() == s
}
```

That can be used to pattern match against `IsUpperCase()`.

Comment: But how the result type of IsUpperCase() depends on the parameters that IsUpperCase() accepts? And why if the result type of IsUpperCase is Boolean then it might not accept any arguments?

Comment: @Zapadlo `IsUpperCase()` doesn't accept parameters, it receives them back. A pattern match works the opposite of a function call. Where `X(a, b)` pass parameter "a" and "b" to "X" outside a pattern match, in a pattern match "a" and "b" are _returned_ from "X". Well, here we have `unapply` returning a `String`, but you are saying you don't expect it to.

Answer (score 5):

Because for the first example you need to write something like `case u @ IsUpperCase(v) =>` or `case u @ IsUpperCase(_) =>`, which means "match `IsUpperCase(v)` and if it succeeds bind the *original* string to `u`".

Comment: But why I should't write this argument when the result type is Boolean?