# case with an @ symbol in akka

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I was reading through some examples of Akka, specifically the ChatServer example by Jonas Boner, and I came across case msg @ GetChatLog =>. I've tried to figure out what the @ symbol means by searching in akka documentation and various articles about pattern matching in scala with no luck. Does anyone have an idea of what it means?

Comment: It's called [variable binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284048/scala-pattern-matching-variable-binding).

Comment: In general, scala symbols are documented here https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-symbols.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

@ binds the object being pattern matched to a variable. msg @ GetCharLog will result in msg holding a reference to the GetCharLog object, which isn't very useful. A better example is msg @ Foo(a, b, c), which will result in msg holding a reference to the instance of Foo that is matched on, which lets you forward the received message (for example) without needing to construct another instance of Foo with a, b, and c.

Comment: another good example is if you have some specific types you want to match you can do `case m @ (_: A | _: B ) => ` which reads as "case m is something of type A or something of type B"

Comment: Interesting; as far as I can tell, this is only available in Akka. Seems like it would be convenient for Scala to have in general.

Comment: @bbarker it is in scala:
```scala> Some(1) match { case outer @ Some(inner) => s"$outer, $inner" }
res0: String = Some(1), 1```

Comment: Where is @ defined? Has anyone else noticed that it’s impossible to search scaladocs for these functions defined as special characters? When they’re the least descriptive names - and therefore the functions you’re most likely to need to look up???